# Making a boolean true for x seconds when condition is met, then reverting it to false

Tags: java, boolean

I'm making a `boolean` so if a certain condition is met, it will return true for 3 seconds, but after that it will return false again.

So it's like

```
private boolean timedBoolean() {

         if(//condition to set boolean true){ 
            return true;
         }

        //if condition isn't met for 3 seconds
         return false;
     }
```

Been thinking about this for an hour now. Researched SO before I asked.

Comment: have you tried `Thread.sleep(3000);` ?

Comment: making the thread sleep would cause problems in my application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private long lastTrueTime;
private boolean timedBoolean() {
        long now= System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(/*condition to set boolean true*/){ 
            lastTrueTime=now;
            return true;
        }

        if (lastTrueTime+3000<now)
            return false;

        return true;
}
```

Comment: you beat me with you quick typing.  However I think you have a typo with your if statement

Comment: `if (lastTrueTime+3000<now)
            return false;

        return true;` <=> `return lastTrueTime+3000<now`.

Comment: Simple and effective.

Comment: `if (booleanExpr) return true; return false;` is generally agreed to be less readable than `return booleanExpr;` (except to beginners).

Answer (score 5):

Remember the moment at which your 3-second period started:

```
private volatile long start;
```

and have the method check the elapsed time:

```
private boolean timedBoolean() {
    if (conditionMet()) {
      start = System.nanoTime();
      return true;
    }
    return System.nanoTime()-start < TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(3);
}
```

Comment: Any performance problem using nanos rather than ms when such precision is not required

Comment: No problem; `nanoTime` is the recommended method to measure *intervals* as opposed to wall-clock time instants. Also note that *precision* != *accuracy*. `currentTimeMillis` has way less than millisecond accuracy and `nanoTime` has way less than nanosecond accuracy.

Comment: Effective, but I don't think an import is necessary. (TimeUnit)

Comment: What's your preference? Reimplementation?

Answer (score 2):

Here'a a `Timed` class.

For a certain amount of time after you call it's `tick` method it will return one value from its `get` method - then it will revert to it's other value. You should be able to use it for your case.

```
class Timed<T> {
  private final T recent;
  private final T old;
  private final long wait;
  // Last time we ticked.
  private long time = 0;

  public Timed (T recent, T old, long wait ) {
    this.recent = recent;
    this.old = old;
    this.wait = wait;
  }

  public T get () {
    return System.currentTimeMillis() < time + wait ? recent: old;
  }
  public void tick () {
    time = System.currentTimeMillis();
  }
}

...
Timed<Boolean> timed = new Timed<>(Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.FALSE, 3 * 1000);
```